# vue.js: How can nextTick ensure that dom render is completed after data change?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue, the doc tells us that if you want to do something (e.g. get the new width & height of an element) after render is completed, you should do it in callback of `Vue.nextTick(callback)`. But at few times I found it didn't work (I don't know if others found it not work at times too) and must resort to `setTimeout` to fix it.

I doubt how `nextTick` can ensure that render is completed totally. I read the source code and find that it may use `Promise.then`, `setImmediate` or `setTimeout(cb, 0)` to run your code at the `nextTick`. I think dom rendering can happen any time between ticks of event loop. So the all the internal methods used by `nextTick` can't ensure that the new rendering work is done.

[Note] I am not to discuss whether it is a good way to call `nextTick` to resolve
some problem, it is another question. My point is why it can do what it provided(dom render is completed).

Can someone give me an explanation about it? Thanks.

Comment: Often times, I find when a person is trying to use `nextTick()`, its typically *not* the right tool for the job, and vue has something else that is more fitting. Please provide a code example we can use to replicate your issue

Comment: @Derek in complex web app, `nextTick` will be used more often. Because it will require element's geometry & position calculation more often. And these calculation must be done after render is totally completed.

Comment: I disagree, Vue has hooks into an elements render state, which can be used to determine if the element has been rendered or not

Comment: How do you read the new width and height of your element? How do you apply them?

Comment: @tomwang1013 please see: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks

Comment: @tomwang1013 see my comment. I said nothing about the `updated` hook

Comment: @Derek sorry, but is the doc you mentioned relevant to this topic? can you please give more hint?

Comment: Please read the documentation. It is clear on its usage and it fits in this situation.

Comment: do you do DOM modification outside of Vue? namely performing modification using `document.querySelector` or jquery or etc? Btw, I don't understand Derek's points either

Comment: @JacobGoh no, i just need some element's style(e.g.width/height, etc) after render is completed, so i use nextTick. I don't do DOM  modification outside of Vue. Anyway, as is said, i don't care about whether use nextTick is a good idea, but why it can do what it provided(ensure dom render is completed)

Answer (score 5):

`nextTick` does not guarantee the DOM render is completed, it just guarantee that the DOM structure is updated.

You can access the updated DOM using something like `this.$refs.p.innerHTML` inside nextTick's callback.
But you may not see that content on the screen yet.

`nextTick` put your callback inside a microtask queue, after all the microtasks is completed then the browser will have a chance to render the new content.

If you want to wait for the content to display on the screen, you can use `setImmediate` (IE only) or `setTimeout(fn, 0)` which has lower priority than the render task so it will execute after the new content is displayed.

See this answer for example fiddle:
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/does-nexttick-work-weirdly/42918/7